# Shortcut to a constructor call

Tags: javascript

Below, is a simplified version of my *App*, the following code works as intended. I can see 4 logs in my console with the arguments I passed to `SayHello`.

```
var App = {};

(function(that){

    that.SayHello = function(){
        console.log( arguments );
        return {
            doSomething: function(){
                console.log('done');
            }
        };
    };

    var obj = {
        t: new that.SayHello( 'a', 1 ),
        r: new that.SayHello( 'b', 2 ),
        b: new that.SayHello( 'c', 3 ),
        l: new that.SayHello( 'd', 4 )
    };

}(App));
```

**issue:** I am trying to create a "shortcut" to `new that.SayHello` as follow:

```
var Greet = function(){
        return new that.SayHello;
    },
    obj = {
        t: Greet( 'a', 1 ),
        r: Greet( 'b', 2 ),
        b: Greet( 'c', 3 ),
        l: Greet( 'd', 4 )
    };
```

The console logs 4 empty arrays. Wich means the `arguments` failed to pass.

I also tried `return new that.SayHello.apply(this, arguments);` and `return new that.SayHello.call(this, arguments);`.

**How can I pass ALL `Greet`'s `arguments` to `that.SayHello` ?**
Knowing that I have to initialize `that.SayHello` using `new that.SayHello` or else my code breaks.

I am looking for a general solution for any number of `arguments`, I don't want to pass the `arguments` one by one.

This code is also available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pierre/AgBaQ/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var Greet = function(){
    var result = that.SayHello.prototype;
    that.SayHello.apply(result, arguments);
    return result;
}
```

You should know that `apply` applies `arguments` to object `result`. Predefining `result` as a `SayHello` prototype will give you what you want.

**EDIT**

Unfortunetly the code above will alter the prototype of `SayHello`. This is obviously unwanted behaviour so to avoid this I think we should copy the prototype object. For example use the following code

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

var Greet = function(){
    var result = clone(that.SayHello.prototype);
    that.SayHello.apply(result, arguments);
    return result;
}
```

I've found this simple version of `clone` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript#answer-728694). There are many problems with it and you should check other answers. For example using jQuery's `$.extend({},originalObject)` might be a good idea.

Note that if you don't care about prototype chaining (although you should) you can always do something very simple like this:

```
var Greet = function(){
    var result = {};
    that.SayHello.apply(result, arguments);
    return result;
}
```

If you don't care about older browsers (ECMAScript 5) then you can use `Object.create` method:

```
var Greet = function(){
    var result = Object.create(that.SayHello.prototype);
    that.SayHello.apply(result, arguments);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Pierre There was one major bug in my answer, I've updated it.